# why does urllib.urlopen(url) fail while urllib2.urlopen(url) works. What specifically about the server response is causing this?

Tags: python, http, urllib2, urllib

I just want a better idea of what's going on here, I can of course "work around" the problem by using urllib2.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = "http://www.crutchfield.com/S-pqvJFyfA8KG/p_15410415/Dynamat-10415-Xtreme-Speaker-Kit.html"

# urllib2 works fine (foo.headers / foo.read() also behave)
foo = urllib2.urlopen(url)

# urllib throws errors though, what specifically is causing this?
bar = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

http://pae.st/AxDW/ shows this code in action with the exception/stacktrace.  `foo.headers` and `foo.read()` work fine

**stu@sente.cc ~ $**: `curl -I "http://www.crutchfield.com/S-pqvJFyfA8KG/p_15410415/Dynamat-10415-Xtreme-Speaker-Kit.html"`

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Object Moved
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /S-FSTWJcduy5w/p_15410415/Dynamat-10415-Xtreme-Speaker-Kit.html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=FSTWJcduy5w; domain=.crutchfield.com; expires=Fri, 22-Feb-2013 22:06:43 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: SYSTEMID=0; domain=.crutchfield.com; expires=Fri, 22-Feb-2013 22:06:43 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: SESSIONDATE=02/23/2012 17:07:00; domain=.crutchfield.com; expires=Fri, 22-Feb-2013 22:06:43 GMT; path=/
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
HostName: cws105
Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2012 22:06:43 GMT
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This server is both non-deterministic and sensitive to HTTP version.  `urllib2` is HTTP/1.1, `urllib` is HTTP/1.0.  You can reproduce this by running `curl --http1.0 -I "http://www.crutchfield.com/S-pqvJFyfA8KG/p_15410415/Dynamat-10415-Xtreme-Speaker-Kit.html"`
 a few times in a row.  You should see the output `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` occasionally; that's the error `urllib` is reporting.  (If you re-issue the request a bunch of times with urllib, it should succeed sometimes.)

Comment: Seems that urllib.urlopen(url) works just under 10% time.  hooray for non-deterministic servers!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem. I simply using now the urrlib instead of urllib2 and anything works fine thank you all :)